# Variable not taking correct value

Tags: variables, nslocalizedstring

I got this piece of code:

```
- (void)ShowTypeOfExercises:(id)sender
{
NSString *lstrGroupTitle;
NSString *lstrGroupNumber;

if(([sender tag]) == 1)
{
    lstrGroupTitle = NSLocalizedString(@" Chest", @"");
    lstrGroupNumber = @"  1";
}
.
.
.
.
[lstrGroupNumber release];
[lstrGroupTitle release];

Exercises *objExercises = [[Exercises alloc] initWithNibName:@"Exercises" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objExercises animated:YES];
}
```

This code block works fine first time I click it, but on the second click it always crashes. It crashes because, amazingly, lstrGroupTitle gets a weird value. How can it possibly get a wrong value in this easy function?

Note: lstrGroupNumber works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this the case is, but this code calls release even if [sender tag] != 1 and the variables were not allocated at all. If this happens it could lead to weird values or to crashes.